# Detecting Ctrl - F11 with javascript

Tags: javascript, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I googled the answer in couple ways but couldn't find a good answer without any library. It was also not asked in stackoverflow. So I thought it might also be helpful to someone else as well. I know I can detect window keyup or down event but how can I detect Ctrl + F11 event in the same time?

```
$(window).keypress(function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.which;
    if (keyCode == 122) {
        console.log("You pressed f11");
    }
})
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using Javascript:

```js
document.onkeydown = keydown;

function keydown(e) {
  var evtobj = window.event ? event : e
  if (evtobj.keyCode == 122 && evtobj.ctrlKey)
    alert("[JS] Ctrl + F11 pressed");
}
```

```html
<p>Press Ctrl + F11</p>
```

More Info:

- [`KeyboardEvent.ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey)
- [`Keycodes Info`](http://keycode.info/)

---

### Using jQuery:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 122 && e.ctrlKey)
    alert("[jQuery] Ctrl + F11 pressed");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Press Ctrl + F11</p>
```

More Info:

- [`Event Object`](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)